# Form with multiple identical lines

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am writing a Flask app in which the user will have to enter all of the university courses they are planning to take for a semester.  The data required is a code (e.g. 'CMPT') and a number (e.g. '101').

I want the user to be able to input *up to* 10 courses.  I would like to do this by reusing the `CourseForm` I created, instead of manually creating the fields for each course.  I have played around with `FieldList` and `FormField` to create a new form that uses the `CourseForm`, but I can't get it to display properly.

How can I create a form that has 10 slots for courses?

```
class CourseForm(Form):
    code = SelectField('Course Code', choices=CHOICES)
    number = IntegerField('Course Number')

@app.route(...)
def index():
    form = CourseForm()
    return render_template('main.html', title='Main', form=form)
```

`main.html`:

```
...
<form action="" method="post" name="course">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>{{ form.code() }} {{ form.number() }}</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with `FieldList` and `FormField`.

Start with your `CourseForm`.

```
class CourseForm(Form):
    code = SelectField('Course Code', choices=CHOICES)
    number = IntegerField('Course Number')
```

Then you'll need to encapsulate it inside another form. For the sake of this example I'll call it `RegisteredCoursesForm`. You can use `max_entries` to limit the number of entries to 10. If you always want 10 entries to be available, even if they won't all be filled in, you can also include `min_entries`.

```
class RegisteredCoursesForm(Form):
    courses = FieldList(FormField(CourseForm), min_entries=10, max_entries=10)
    # Any other fields can go here (e.g., user_id).
```

You'll want to pass this new form to your template instead of `CourseForm`.

```
def index():
    form = RegisteredCoursesForm()
    return render_template('main.html', title='Main', form=form)
```

Finally you can iterate over the `courses` field to get all of the fields contained without `CourseForm`.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="course">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {% for course_form in form.courses %}
        <p>{{ course_form.code }} {{ course_form.number }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much!  I was pretty close to getting that, but I was thinking I would need a list of the `FieldList(FormField(CourseForm))` objects, but I see now why that wouldn't work.